# How to upload image from react native to Django along with name and email

Tags: django, react-native, serialization, model

Does any body know how we send image,email and name from React Native to Django

```
              </Text>
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row',}}>
                  <View style={{marginTop:20,}}>
                      <Text style={{borderWidth:1, backgroundColor:'white', 
                      width:50, height:50, borderRadius:40, textAlign:'center', alignContent:'center',
                      justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center' ,alignItems:'center',paddingTop:14,}}>
                        1
                      </Text>
                      <Text style={{fontSize:19,color:'white',textAlign:'center', alignContent:'center',
                      justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center' ,alignItems:'center',paddingTop:14,}}>
                        Photos
                      </Text>
                      <Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:7,textAlign:'center', alignContent:'center',
                      justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center' ,alignItems:'center',paddingTop:14,}}>
                        Enter all the information about
                        {"\n"}
                        your car
                      </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{paddingLeft:10,marginTop:20,}}>
                      <Text style={{borderWidth:1, backgroundColor:'white', 
                      width:50, height:50, borderRadius:40, textAlign:'center', alignContent:'center',
                      justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center' ,alignItems:'center',paddingTop:14,}}>
                        2
                      </Text>
                      <Text style={{fontSize:19,color:'white',textAlign:'center', alignContent:'center',
                      justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center' ,alignItems:'center',paddingTop:14,}}>
                        Photos
                      </Text>
                      <Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:7,textAlign:'center', alignContent:'center',
                      justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center' ,alignItems:'center',paddingTop:14,}}>
                        Upload pictures of your 
                        {"\n"}
                        cars from all angles
                      </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{paddingLeft:10,marginTop:20,}}>
                      <Text style={{borderWidth:1, backgroundColor:'white', 
                      width:50, height:50, borderRadius:40, textAlign:'center', alignContent:'center',
                      justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center' ,alignItems:'center',paddingTop:14,}}>
                        3
                      </Text>
                      <Text style={{fontSize:19,color:'white',textAlign:'center', alignContent:'center',
                      justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center' ,alignItems:'center',paddingTop:14,}}>
                        Photos
                      </Text>
                      <Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:7,textAlign:'center', alignContent:'center',
                      justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center' ,alignItems:'center',paddingTop:14,}}>
                        Add the price at which you
                        {"\n"}
                        are will to sell the car
                      </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
         </ImageBackground>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'green', width:'100%', height:400, marginTop:120,}}>
        <Text style={{alignSelf:'center', fontSize:25, color:'white',}}>
            Car Information
          </Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputstyle}
                label = "City"
                value = {city}
                mode  = "outlined"
                onChangeText= {Text => setcity(Text) }
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputstyle}
                label = "Car Information"
                value = {carinfo}
                mode  = "outlined"
                onChangeText= {Text => setcarinfo(Text) }
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputstyle}
                label = "Milage"
                value = {milage}
                mode  = "outlined"
                onChangeText= {Text => setmilage(Text) }
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputstyle}
                label = "Price"
                value = {price}
                mode  = "outlined"
                onChangeText= {Text => setprice(Text) }
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputstyle}
                label = "Company"
                value = {company}
                mode  = "outlined"
                onChangeText= {Text => setcompany(Text) }
            />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
    inputstyle:{
        
        marginTop:15,
        width:200,
        alignSelf:'center',
    }

})

export default add_post
```

I send this data with image from react native to Django any one know how to send this data

i send this data with image from react native to Django any one know how to send this data.
i does not get code from internet
i search whole internet but cannot get code from where i can send data from react native to django along with other field

Comment: Hi! Can you elaborate your issue clear? Seems your question is pretty unclear for us to answer it :)

Comment: how can i upload photo from react to django. when i press button my photo and my text upload on django